# Log in to multiple tokens and perform action

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, command, member

I'm making a command that connects several bots at the same time, but I'm having a problem, when all the bots call, I want the question to appear only once in the console asking what the person wants to do, when they answer the script it will save their answer and it will run on all bots.

````
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const auth = require('./token.json')
const readline = require('readline')
const fs = require('fs');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});


rl.question("Choose between 1 or 2. ", name => {
    if(name === "1") {
        rl.question("Teste? ", info1 => {
            console.log(info1)
            rl.close();
        });
    } else if(name === "2") {
        rl.question("Teste2? ", info2 => {
            console.log(info2)
            rl.close();
        })}
    ;
});
for (const token of auth.token) {
    const client = new Discord.Client()
    
    client.on('ready', () => {
        //---------> How to see / execute what was chosen in line 12 appear here <---------\\
    })
    
    client.login(token).catch(e => {
        const index = auth.token.indexOf(token);
        if (index > -1) {
            auth.token.splice(index, 1)
        }

        fs.writeFile ("token.json", JSON.stringify(auth), function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        })
    });
}```
````

Comment: use a global variable

Comment: What is the current behaviour?